# Set chmod 0666 manually

Tags: php, chmod

I have this code

```
if (!is_writable(ABSPATH . "/_config.php")) {
if (!chmod(ABSPATH . "/_config.php", 0666)) {
return "Cannot change permissions of config.php <br /> You must do it manually: set chmod 0666 for file system/_config.php";
};
}
```

Now i have to set chmod 0666 for _config.php manually. How? 
I tried this but nothing happened

```
chmod("/message/system/_config.php", 0666);
```

Someone knows what i have to do?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have to chmod _config.php manually from your unix terminal.

`chmod 0666 ./_config.php` after you have `cd`'d to the directory containing your file.